# Keeping track of long repetitive operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my code I need to perform an operation on lots of different postcodes that can take up to a few seconds each operation and can include thousand of postcodes that need to be processed. I need to be able to keep track of it and restart it if it is terminated for whatever reason.

I had the idea to create a search entity like so:

```
public class Search
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostCode> PostCodes { get; set; }
}

public class PostCode
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am having trouble working out how I keep track of it. My first thought was after each successful operation to remove the `PostCode` from the collection in `Search` and save it so each time I load the object it will have only the unprocessed postcodes but when I do this it throws an exception.

Like so:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    foreach (var pc in search.PostCodes)
    {
        DoSomeStuff(pc);
        search.PostCodes.Remove(pc);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I understand this is because I can't change the object I am enumerating over but for some reason I can't think of a simple non-convoluted way to keep track of the search in the database. Also due to the fact that there are many thousand postcodes I am concerned here about performance also.

Can anyone suggest how I should be keeping track of the search?

**EDIT**

So if I keep track of number processed in a `completed` property will this work properly?

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    foreach (var pc in search.PostCodes.Skip(search.Completed))
    {
        DoSomeStuff(pc);
        search.Completed ++;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If I save and then load an entity with Entity Framework does it always keep the `IEnumerable` in the same order?

**Edit #2**

This is where in my actual code I load the search object:

```
rs = db.RadarSearches.Include("PostCodes").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Keyword.Value == keyword && x.Complete == false);
```

I guess if I enforce ordering here then I can make it consistent.  How do I order the nested `PostCodes` collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. store the result as an array and store that array in a file, so that you can resume (assuming the search result may vary at different times). with the file you need to save the index at where you have been. on resume of your process you load the array from the file and the last successful processed index.
2. you can store the whole object and remove successful processed ones, but for performance's sake you just save the file on every 5th or 10th procession.

Comment: I need to store the progress in the database.  If I save the object and load it via entity framework am I guaranteed that the IEnumberable will be in the same order?

Comment: You can make sure by sorting (if allowed) each time before starting the process.